# Dictionaries within dictionaries etc - how to format it correctly?

Tags: python, json

I have a dataframe obtained from a `.json` file which is in a almost unreadable format to me. I'm not used to working with `json` files - maybe there is a smart way that I'm not aware of?
Here's an extract from the dataframe (one row)
[image]

How do I open up the columns such as `comments` so that it is in columns as well? I open the json file with this command:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_json("the_file.json", lines = True)
```

When I try to flatten one of the columns in the the data frame like this:

```
df_nested_list = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['comments'])
```

I get the error

```
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 13661)
```

... I think it's because some of the cells contain lists within lists within lists, and I don't know how to work with this kind of data since I'm used to word with data in a tidy format. My end goal is to have a totally flat dataframe all along.

Comment: Do you want to pretty-print this? Try *Command Palette* > *Format Document* in VS Code.

Comment: If you are trying to load the json file in pandas dataframe, then I suggest looking at read_json() or json_normalize() function of pandas library.

Comment: Whitespace isn't significant in JSON. IJSON files aren't meant for humans to begin with. It doesn't matter if the entire document is a single line or multiple. If you want to pretty print this JSON document, you can use the formatting functionality in your editor, IDE or an online formatter

Comment: BTW what is the question?

Comment: The question is: How to I make output the data in a tidy format

Comment: That's not a programming problem. Use your editor's pretty printing or formatting feature, or a online formatter. JSON parsers don't care about whitespace outside strings

Comment: I'm not sure I've made myself clear enough. I'll edit the post, 2 sek

Comment: That's a completely different question from the previous one. Now you're asking how to flatten the dataframe. You can do that with `json_normalize`

Answer (score 1):

Play around with something like for nested (dictionaries of dictionary) dictionary -

```
with open('file.json','r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

df_nested_list = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['metadata'])
```

Comment: I'm just getting the error: ```TypeError: string indices must be integers```

Comment: Or this error: ```JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 13661)```

Comment: you will need to play around with json_normalize function, or best do read_json , and then expand individual series as you see fit. list could be done using series.str.split() or dictionaries can be manipulated using series.items() etc.
Another way would be to write a function and then apply using df.apply. Once you get the desired output, you can optimize it in pythonic way.